# Buscar una dirección en Google Maps y que el resultado aparezca en otra página

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, api, map

Mi consulta es, si es que se puede realizar una búsqueda con el buscador de Google Maps que tengo en mi sitio y el resultado de esa búsqueda me aparezca en otra página.

Para poder implementar el buscador use los ejemplos de [Google (Aquí)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox?hl=ES). Entonces lo que hice en la página 1 es sacar el buscador del mapa e implementarlo en un sector de sitio a mi gusto:

**Página 1**

```
input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Busca una lugar, una dirección o algún comercio.">

function initAutocomplete() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {
                lat: -33.4488897,
                lng: -70.6692655
            },
            zoom: 9,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });

        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);


        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
            searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

        var markers = [];
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
            var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

            if (places.length == 0) {
                return;
            }

            // Clear out the old markers.
            markers.forEach(function(marker) {
                marker.setMap(null);
            });
            markers = [];

            // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            places.forEach(function(place) {
                if (!place.geometry) {
                    console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
                    return;
                }
                var icon = {
                    url: place.icon,
                    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                };

                // Create a marker for each place.
                markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    icon: icon,
                    title: place.name,
                    position: place.geometry.location
                }));

                if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                    // Only geocodes have viewport.
                    bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
                } else {
                    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
                }
            });
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
    }
```

En la página 2 donde quiero que aparezca el resultado de la búsqueda hecha en la página 1, tengo lo mismo que en el enlace [Ejemplo de Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox?hl=ES).

Entonces no sé como hacer que el buscador de la página 1 este conectado con el mapa de la página 2.

Answer (score 1):

Si usas PHP podrías guardar el resultado en una variable de $_SESSION.

Si no, otra opción podría ser guardar el resultado en una cookie y leerla en la siguiente página.

Otra opción, que quizá se ajuste más a tu necesidad es utilizar localStorage, similar al uso de Cookies.

La documentación la puedes encontrar en [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Para guardar la información en la página 1:

```
localStorage.setItem('resultado_maps', JSON.stringify(map_result));
```

Para obtener la información en la página 2:

```
localStorage.getItem('resultado_maps');
```

Comment: Y como hago para que se lea en la siguiente página?

Comment: Actualizo mi respuesta.